# How to build and organize menus with rich taxonomies and complex view-based menus

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, routes

I would like to hear your insights about strategies on organizing menus. I mean two main approaches: having each menu header as an individual Drupal menu vs. having all menus grouped as one big menu, perhaps named "Main menu".

I built quite a large site where I had to use such modules as [OM Maximenu](http://drupal.org/project/om_maximenu), [Taxonomy menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu)/[Taxonomy menu trails](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_trails), [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block), [Sitemap](http://drupal.org/project/sitemap), [DHTML Menu](http://drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu). Without much knowledge about Drupal and the consequences of my choice, just to keep my progress on, I took my liberty to sometimes put a group of menu items as individual menus, sometimes I grouped them together (this was the case of Taxonomy menu and Menu Block where I could define the level at which menu starts).

Then, when I installed Sitemap I saw that my menu organization revealed to public. This was also a lesson.

Although everything works OK, I don't feel alright with this kind of mess. Especially, after some time I know I will have to do a repetitive research on how a particular menu is built, rather than have it intuitively solved right away.

**My question**: What is your preferred way to build and organize menus with rich taxonomies and complex view-based menus (OM Maximenu)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, we put all of the site sections in the main menu.

Each site section will get its own Drupal menu.  How items get into menus varies widely project-to-project, but we will rely on path-alias define section organization as much as possible.

Each section will have its own [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) pages, where the site section gets used as the context / selection rule (typically by path matching), and the menu is placed in a content area.

Occasionally, we will have a site section taxonomy, which gets used inside a custom block to display the proper menu.